# Chrome don't show native options dialog in extension

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Suddenly catch strange error with chrome extensions.

If add something style for body example `body { margin: 0, padding: 0 }` chrome don't showing options dialog (native). Url changes, we can see options.html source, but modal don't appear.

I have no idea why...

**UPD.**

Set height and width for body solved my problem.

Comment: try to put a semicolon between properties instead the simple comma.

Comment: Sure must be semicolon. It's typo. But problem is solved. If changing body we must set with and height.